# return data from backend in dropdownlist with settimeout

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, settimeout

I do an api call to the backend to populate a dropdownlist, and it works. But the problem is that only if the user clicks two times on the dropdownlist the data will be shown in the dropdown list. But in the console I see the data is loaded when I click on the dropdownlist once.

So I try it with a setTimeout. But that doesn't work.

This is the api call:

```
  getQrCodes() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrCodeDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection()
          .pipe(tap(console.log));
    }, 1000);
  }
```

And this is the template:

```
<div class="search-select searchoptions"  
    *ngIf=" selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
    <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" 
         [(ngModel)]="selectedValueOptie" (click)="getQrCodes()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (returnQrCodes$ | async)" 
                value="option.value"> {{ option.qrCode }} </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </div>
```

So my question is: How to show the data in the dropdown list if you click on it just once?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with the **`change`** event attribute:

```
  getQrCodes() {
      this.returnQrCodes$ = this.qrCodeDefinitonService.getDefinitionForSelection()
          .pipe(tap(console.log));
  }


<div class="search-select searchoptions"  
    *ngIf=" selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
    <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" 
         [(ngModel)]="selectedValueOptie" (change)="getQrCodes()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (returnQrCodes$ | async)" 
                value="option.value"> {{ option.qrCode }} </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make first click, there are no options in the select control and so it doesn't try and open the panel. Then your async method loads the options into the DOM and on the next click it will open.

So try to include at least one `<mat-option>` in your `<mat-select>`.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" 
     [(ngModel)]="selectedValueOptie" (click)="getQrCodes()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of returnQrCodes$ | async as codes" 
            value="option.value"> {{ option.qrCode }} </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngIf="!codes"
            value="empty">Data is loading</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </div>
```